# What data structure should I use for storing my data?

Tags: data-structures, database-theory, hash-tables, search-problem, storage

I am currently looking for a way in which I can store my data, and quickly look it up.

What currently seem to be the best idea is to use a hash map.

reasons:

- To identify what item I am looking for, one need to extract a certain
  set of features from the data, which can be used as a key to extract
  the item.

Problem here is that the features could contain noise,
   making the key <-> item match not 100% perfect.

In such case I need to find the key which matches the feature set the best? Or a set of keys which matches the feature set the best. But how do i do that?

The feature vector is 512 long.

sorting would be a possibility? but how should I sort such a matrix?

And given the complications I am facing, is using a hash map the right choice? or is something better?